# Is this particular Parallel.For() loop thread-safe?

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, thread-safety, critical-section

```
Parallel.For(0, someStringArray.Count, (i) =>
{
    someStringArray[i] = someStringArray[i].Trim();
});
```

I'm sure that only **reading** through a collection with `Parallel.For` is considered thread-safe.

**EDIT:** The array is not being accessed through other parts of code.

Comment: @MarcGravell it's a good bonus if the collection is large enough, yes.

Comment: Probably, but we don't know if anything else is concurrently accessing the array... Why not just `var someNewArray = someStringArray.AsParallel().Select(s => s.Trim()).ToArray()`?

Comment: @spender There's a lot more going on when you go down that LINQ expression road. I edited my question, thanks!

Comment: I'm gonna say "safe" then.

Comment: If this is the only code accessing the array while it's running, it's fine

Comment: @spender could you, or someone elaborate when exactly an array, or any collection falls under the doubts of thread safety? As far as I'm aware, if 2 threads are accessing/reading the **same** element, problems tend to arise. Is that the gist of it?

Comment: @SpiritBob Indeed... If you're sure no single element of the array will be written to whilst another thread is reading or writing to it then no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this particular `Parallel.For()` loop thread-safe?

Depending on the implementation of the type of `someStringArray`, it is as long as you are not modiying the collection itself while enumerating.

At no time are two threads modifying the same element in the collection in your example.

Generally speaking, collections are not considered thread-safe because their internal logic may fail if you for example read an item from one thread while another thread adds an item and cause the collection to resize (and items to get copied) in the middle of the read operation.

This shouldn't happen with fixed-size arrays though. `List<T>` uses an array under the hood but that's an implementation detail that you shouldn't really rely on in the general case.

Comment: "_because you are not modifying the collection itself_" -  Isn't it modifying when I edit an  already existing element in the collection with a new element?

Comment: @SpiritBob: Well, it depends on the implementation. What is `someStringArray`?

Comment: It's an array, or to be exactly precise `somethingDefinedLikeThis[]`.

Comment: @SpiritBob: Then you are safe. Did you see my update? It should answer your question.